# Three.js Skeletal Animation Export Issue

Tags: animation, three.js, blender, skinning

I've been working with an animator to help with my game. The animations all work fine using morph targets, but the file size just gets way too large. Skeletal animations are the answer. We've spent a week working to get the animations exported from blender correctly.

After reading many many articles we were able to get basic animations working correctly. I make sure to set the armature to rest pose and export on the first frame and all that, but the more complicated animations are off.

You can see in this example here (click to cycle animations):

http://www.titansoftime.com/beta/animation2.html

My animator said the problems are related to bone constraints using his controllers. He said his technique is called "Inverse Kinematics".

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Your link doesn't work

Comment: this answer might be your help  
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18770716/1512287

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. For one you can not scale the geometry in the json loader (however you can scale the mesh object once created).

The main thing is that my animator was using inverse kinematics, which apparently three.js does not play nice with.