# Three.js - avatar animation

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, blender, collada

I have a question about three.js library. I was wondering how i can create an animation, in which an avatar, which was exported from Blender to Collada format (.dae), moves an arm or a leg, using WebGL (three.js) library not Blender.

Comment: have you checked the [examples](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_collada_skinning) ?

Comment: I haven't seen anything like this in the examples. I don't want to import the animation, I want to create an animation with three.js library. Most of those examples are imported animation from some 3D computer graphic software.

Comment: sorry i misread. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433474/dynamic-bones-animation-in-three-js) probably is what you look for @Erica Okamura

Comment: I want to manipulate a Collada file, not JSON. I have tried to install the JSON plug-in on Blender, but it is not working properly.

Comment: it should not matter what file format you are importing, the movement/animation code will be the same.

Comment: Maybe you should check three.js issues on github, or post one if the blender json exporter is not working on your OS. It has been rewritten recently and provides a lot of options. My experience on windows is that blender somehow returns an error when i try to export the first time, but there never is none in the json file.

Comment: Actually, I have been reading a lot on the internet about exporting to JSON from Blender and I have found out that the JSON exporter is working properly, but I wasn't exporting the skinning/bones (you have to select those options when exporting to JSON).

Answer (score 0):

What I always do is modelling inside Cinema 4D and export this as a .fbx format.

Import the fbx file inside blender and export as JSON (using three.js export plugin). 
If you load this JSON file inside Three.js you'll get values like reflection with it.

Also not sure why you want to make a .dae file work with Three.js..

Comment: I am trying to use JSON format now with Autodesk 3ds Max. However, the exported JSON file from 3ds Max does not show any data of the bones. Therefore, I cannot create any animation with three.js library. Do you know what the problem might be?

Comment: This might help you http://blog.romanliutikov.com/post/60461559240/rigging-and-skeletal-animation-in-three-js