# Blender animation getting distorted after importing into three.js

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, blender

I am working on a project trying to put animations into a scene using blender and three.js. After hours of messing around with blender and three js i was able to get the the model and animation imported into three js. I used this :https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender to export my blender project into a js file. 
Here is what my animation currently looks like:

http://gyazo.com/5c39d15fd16fa7251dbc527732c2f867

I have a feeling that i am messing up something when exporting to a js file. I am completely new to blender and three js and was hoping that someone else has ran into this problem before. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try starting with something simpler such as importing a cube from blender into Three.js. From that you can check if the problem is something in your model, textures, lights, etc, or in the tool/process you are using to import it.

Comment: Thank you, i went back and tried to animate a simple object and it seemed to work fine. Then i went back to my original and ended up rigging and animating it all over again. I believe it had something to do with me moving my object from the origin/scaling the object when creating the first animation. In addition, i followed this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18770716 and set the position of both my mesh and armature before exporting to a js file. I am still not completely sure what caused this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using the option "apply modifiers" when exporting to JSON always causes distortions for me.

[image: Blender "apply modifiers" option while exporting]

It is completely reproducable.
As soon as I tick it -> distortions.
Untick -> no distortions.

Hope this somehow helps somebody.